# How to use Google Cloud Translation V3 with API KEY in C# client library?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, api-key, google-cloud-translate

I want to use Google Translation V3 with [C# client lib google provides](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v3/overview-v3).
but what I can find all is using **service account** to authenticate.

I prefer to use **API key** as an authentication method instead of service account since I'll build this app to user's mobile and I don't want user to have my service account file.

but In [google's official document](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/quickstart#translate_v3_translate_text-csharp) I can only find the example to authenticated by service account.

so how can I use API key with C# lib to authenticated and use Google Cloud Translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use an API Key.

You will need to design a service that authorizes your users and your service will make translation requests on their behalf using a service account. You could also issue short-lived access tokens using your service account and then the client can make API requests using that access token.

Note: API Keys are now legacy and most Google Cloud services no longer support API Keys.

Comment: That will be a too large scale feature for me...but thanks, I really can't use an API key in google cloud V3. I use V2 instead and it works. Of course, it sacrifices some advanced feature of V3 translate(glossary, batch...etc)